# What if someone knows the Secret Key (signature) of your JSON Web Token?

Tags: access-token, json-web-token

If someone knows the secret key and alters lets say for example the username of the json token and the expiry time, will they be able to access secured data on the sever?

Answer (score 1):

If in "secret key" you refer to the symmetric key used in the HMAC signature then anyone who is in possession of that key can create and sign a valid JWT.

If in "secret key" you refer to the private key used to sign a JWT in the RSA scenario, anyone in possession of that key could create and sign a valid JWT trusted by anyone who is validating using the corresponding public key.

Assuming someone can forge a JWT at will (Is able to sign it correctly after modifying it), this token would be trusted by parties who receive it and its contents would be considered authentic.

So basically, yes.

[Here](https://auth0.com/blog/2015/03/31/critical-vulnerabilities-in-json-web-token-libraries/) is great read describing some vulnerabilities and on the way the general concepts of security in JWT.

Answer (score 0):

You need 5 different parameters to get the access token -

> grant_type, username, password, client_id, client_secret

so, knowing the secret key, username would not get you the Token; Knowing password also would get. It precisely means someone would get the Token only if he/she knows all the parameters, else not!

Comment: Youre referring to OAuth, I'm talking about JSON Web Tokens :)